# How to find a random number between $x$ and $y$

Tags: random

Given some random number function [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/), and some numbers $x$ and $y$, how do you find a random number $r$ such that $r\geq x \wedge r \leq y$?

Previously i've tried (and somewhat failed) with formulas like
$$
r = \text{rand()}\bmod \frac{x}{y}
$$
or
$$
r = \text{rand()}\bmod x + 1
$$
or, given that $y>x$,
$$
r = (\text{rand()}\bmod (y-x))+x
$$
Is there a better or truer way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x \lt y$. The usual pseudo-random number generators produce a number between $0$ and $1$. **Multiply** the result by $y-x$, and then **add** $x$.

This also works fine if $y \lt x$.

Comment: Could you go into further detail about why this works? I have asked this as a [seperate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240330/why-does-muliplying-n-by-a-random-number-give-you-a-random-number-between-0-and) here.

Comment: @JW01: By number here we mean real number, not integer. If we multiply a number between $0$ and $1$ by $c\ne 0$, we certainly get a number between $0$ and $c$. Suppose moreover the random numbers between $0$ and $1$ are uniformly distributed $[0,1]$. Let $U$ be a random variable with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $X=cU$, where for simplicity $c$ is positive. Then for $0\le x\le c$, $\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(cU\le x)=\Pr(U\le x/c=x/c$. This means $X$ has uniform distribution on $[0,c]$. If you wish, differentiate the cdf $x/c$ to get constant density function $1/c$.

Comment: Thanks. Its explained very succinctly. I think I get the gist. p.s I assume that there should be a closing parenthesis just before the final sentence ".This means..." ?

Comment: There should be a closing parenthesis just before the $=$ sign, a few characters before "This means."