# Why does multiplying n by a random number give you a random number between 0 and n?

Tags: random, dice

I have been following the [tutorial at Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/conditionals-application/0#!/exercises/1)

I see that, as part of the process of creating a virtual die we multiply 'a random number between 0 and 1' by 6 to give us a random number between 0 and 6.

Could you break this logic down and explain why this works?

In short I am looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/191785/4603) and asking for a nice simple explanation for why that works.

Comment: fyi - I have come accross a follow-up on the codecademy site that outlines the methodology in further detail and in a clear and simple manner:
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/primitives-development-course/5?curriculum_id=4f4bdd96848740000300026a#!/exercises/0 (It is less assumptive but still does not try to prove it mathematically )

Answer (score 3):

The minimum of the random number is zero.  $0*6=0$.  The maximum of the random number is one.  $1*6=6$.  the numbers were uniform from the minimum to the maximum, and they still are.

Comment: Thanks. [I'm not sure if the 'random number between 0 and 1' could ever be 0 or 1](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5082ce65d7c5a802000066c2). But, either way, that was useful in helping to give me a methodology to look at the problem from a new viewpoint.

Comment: @JW01:  in the mathematical sense, a random in the closed interval [0,1] is at an endpoint with probability zero, so it doesn't matter.  In the computer sense, often the random can be zero but never one.  Sometimes you can't get zero, either.  Multiplying by 6 leaves you the same place.

Comment: @JW01:  Sorta random numbers are easy, and every computing environment gives you a rand function that is very fast.  Really random numbers are hard, and if you want them you should understand a lot of issues that I don't, then ask where your random numbers come from.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I heard a [radio programme about random](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/b00x9xjb/In_Our_Time_Random_and_Pseudorandom/) numbers and it was fascinating at how much there is to it all.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a random number uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. This means that:

$$\text{for any } x \in [0,1], P(X \leq x) = x$$

Now observe that, for any $x \in [0,6]$,

$$P(6X \leq x) = P\left(X \leq \frac{x}{6}\right) = \frac{x}{6}$$

This means that $6X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,6]$. Observe that

$$P(6X \leq x) = \int_{0}^{x}{\frac{1}{6}dx}$$

In other words, $6X$ has constant density 1/6 in $[0,6]$. That's why it's called a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its still all a bit terse. But I guess that's not your fault - I shall have to learn more about the language of maths to grok it.